# rsync giving error when executing witin expect script using cron

Tags: linux, cron, expect, rsync

Here is the problem that i am facing. We are using rsync to backup some files from our servers to a remote location. rysnc runs as a daemon on the server and we pull the files periodically from the remote site, where rsync is setup as a cron job.

A recent security audit revealed that we are using unauthenticated rsync modules and anybody who knows the module name can download the shared files.It was suggested to use rsync authenticated modules and to maintain a secret file.

In order to make the passing of password interactive at the remote site, i used an expect script. Now the problem we are facing is, the script works properly when executed manually. But when executed in cron as a job ,rsync is exiting abruptly and we are getting the following error at the server side.

**"rsync: connection unexpectedly closed rsync error: error in rsync protocol       datastream    (code 12)"**

I tried many of the solutions that i found over the internet, but all in vain.
Please suggest.

The expect script is given here for your reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn /usr/bin/rsync -ruzc *.*.*.*::rsync_module/path/to/dir /tmp/dir --timeout=55
expect {
-re "Password:" {
exp_send "******\r"
}
}
interact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. Removed the interact keyword and added the following lines to the except script. Working fine now.

```
expect eof
sleep 56
exit
```

so the new script look like

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn /usr/bin/rsync -ruzc *.*.*.*::rsync_module/path/to/dir /tmp/dir --timeout=55
expect {
-re "Password:" {
exp_send "******\r"
}
}
expect eof
sleep 56
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Though its not the solution you're looking for, why don't you use key based authentication. You don't have to put passwords in scripts for that purpose.

Comment: thanks you for the reply.I need more clarity on your query. Are you suggesting to use ssh...? As far as i know rsync don't support key based authentication.But you can encrypt the rsync data flow using ssh.